# Competing risk survival curves: R vs Stata

Tags: r, stata, survival

I have done a competing risk survival analysis both with R and Stata. I have two cohorts of patients. However when plotting the curves I obtained very different results.

For R I used the command `cuminc(ftime,fstatus,group,cencode=0)` and then `plot`.
For Stata I used the commands `stcrreg i.cohort_num, compete(thrombosis_competing_analysis == 2)` and `stcurve, cif at1(cohort_num = 1) at2(cohort_num = 2)`.

The curves generated with Stata have 4 “steps”, while the curves generated with R have 2 "steps", and I was wondering whether I made some mistakes.

Many thanks in advance and kind regards

[Curves obtained with R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EChDt.jpg)
[Curves obtained with Stata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp8qv.jpg)

Comment: I think this needs a reproducible data example for anyone to comment usefully,

Comment: The first question to me is: Why does the number of groups differ? In the R plot there are 4 groups and in Stata there are 2. Do you have 2 or 4 groups?

Comment: @Nick: thanks for your interest. I have posted the same question and an extract of my dataset on the StataList forum a few days ago, but unfortunately I did not get any feedback yet https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1549235-stcurve-after-stcrreg

Comment: @Machine: thanks. The standard plot in R has also the two curves for mortality